# How to create jBPM console (Business Central) l10n pack?

Tags: user-interface, localization, internationalization, jbpm

jBPM 6.0 comes with support for several UI languages (English, German, ...)
https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.0/html-single/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/#Available_Languages2

I want to localize the console (aka Business Central) for Russian language.

I tried adding the following localized resources (copied from '..._de' analogs) to the directory `deployments\business-central.war\WEB-INF\classes\org\kie\workbench\client\resources\i18n`:

- AppConstants_ru.properties
- Constants_ru.properties

But switching locale (by adding 'locale=ru') produced no results -- language is still English (locale=de switches to German correctly).

I also found `deployments\business-central.war\WEB-INF\classes\org\kie\workbench\KIEWebapp.gwt.xml` and added `<extend-property name="locale" values="ru"/>` – still no results.

Answer (score 0):

you are definitely in the right direction. First of all you need to check the "ru" is the right locale for Russian. Next you need to  and then compile with the full profile which will do all the language permutations. At that point your language will be available. Notice that you need to recompile the whole application to include the new language.. you cannot just add a language on the fly to it, that is how GWT works.

Regards

Comment: Salaboy, 'ru' definitely is the is right locale :) 'next you need to ... and then' -- the most interesting part of your post is missing! :( And please explain what 'compile with full profile' is -- I have no idea as to what tool in what project to launch.

Comment: LOL.. damn auto correct.. OK so it depends on which project are you looking to compile. But usually you just need to run mvn clean install with -Pfull that will pick up the full profile and compile the gwt application performing all the permutations needed for all the languages. You first need to define which app do you want to compile (jbpm console ng drools-wb or kie-wb)

Comment: I want to localize business-central webapp (don't know which app it is, possibly jbpm-console?) -- could you please post a link to the source code app I need to compile?

Comment: Sure you can find all the projects under github.com/droolsjbpm/ each of the UI modules contains their own i18n packages, so for example the Human Tasks Constants for I18n are here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng -> https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng/tree/master/jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks/jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-client/src/main/resources/org/jbpm/console/ng/ht/client/i18n
Hope this helps